# Pandas: df.iloc working but df.at is giving error for the exact same cell?

Tags: python, pandas

I have those 2 lines, the first one prints ADNER FRANCISCO while the second one gives an error even though they should be identical, right?

```
print(df.iloc[y]['CleanCopy'])
print(df.at[y,'CleanCopy'])
```

The weird thing is that when I tried to re-create the problem with a very simple dataset for testing it works fine and prints 'ADNER FRANCISCO':

```
x = pd.DataFrame([['ba',1],['b',2],['c',' ADNER FRANCISCO ']], columns = ['Item','Value'])
print(x.at[2,'Value'])
```

I can't understand how the exact same command works on one dataset, but not another. Can anyone guess why I'm getting this error? Thanks!

p.s: There's nothing wrong with the first datased because `df.iloc[y]['CleanCopy']` prints 'ADNER FRANCISCO' too...so it's something wtih df.at specifically.

[image: f]

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Someone answered the question...by y I was referring to row number while df.at needs row index. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it happen is your index is not continue.(From 0 to n)

```
x.index=[999,1000,1001]
x.iloc[2]['Value'] # this work since it is located by the position 
' ADNER FRANCISCO '
x.at[2,'Value'] # this failed since it is located by the index value. In my example , the number 2 dose not included in the index value
```

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks! :-) any idea how I could use df.at with rown number instead of row index? The point is that I want to loop through the entire column and change cell values based on a certain criteria. As far as I know df.at is the command that allows you to change the cell value?

Comment: @ShadyMBA let us try `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` before the loop

Comment: This works but unfortunately that will ruin the original index..so probably I'll have to create a copy of the original index before doing the reset and then revert back to the original index which is not a very elegant solution. Any thought of a different command or a simpler approach?

Comment: @ShadyMBA then remove drop `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` your original index will be a new columns nams as 'index'

Comment: Actually I discovered that df.iat uses row number while df.at uses index value so it's easier to use df.iat. Thanks a lot for your help. You saved me hours! :-)